# Issue with running server with React and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, reactjs, npm

I had to reinstall my linux VM that I code on (for school purposes) and after re forking and cloning my app, I cannot start the server. I have run the necessary steps I believe, created and migrated the database, bundle intall, and install and reinstall node_modules...I have a rake task that starts both the api and web page for me simultaneously. Now if I rake start...here is my error message...I have followed to directions on the error message to no success...not sure if I am missing something here.

```
rake start
10:12:38 web.1  | started with pid 3280
10:12:38 api.1  | started with pid 3281
10:12:38 web.1  | 
10:12:38 web.1  | > client@0.1.0 start /home/learn/Development/Code/hoop-it-up/client
10:12:38 web.1  | > react-scripts start
10:12:38 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  | There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
10:12:39 web.1  | It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  | The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  |   "babel-eslint": "10.0.1"
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  | Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
10:12:39 web.1  | However, a different version of babel-eslint was detected higher up in the tree:
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  |   /home/learn/Development/Code/hoop-it-up/node_modules/babel-eslint (version: 10.0.3) 
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  | Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  | If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
10:12:39 web.1  | That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  | To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  |   1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
10:12:39 web.1  |   2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
10:12:39 web.1  |   3. Remove "babel-eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
10:12:39 web.1  |   4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  | In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
10:12:39 web.1  | If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  |   5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
10:12:39 web.1  |      This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  |   6. Check if /home/learn/Development/Code/hoop-it-up/node_modules/babel-eslint is outside your project directory.
10:12:39 web.1  |      For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  |   7. Try running npm ls babel-eslint in your project folder.
10:12:39 web.1  |      This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-eslint.
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  | If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
10:12:39 web.1  | That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  | P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :We hope you find them helpful!
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
10:12:39 web.1  | npm ERR! errno 1
10:12:39 web.1  | npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
10:12:39 web.1  | npm ERR! Exit status 1
10:12:39 web.1  | npm ERR! 
10:12:39 web.1  | npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
10:12:39 web.1  | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
10:12:39 web.1  | 
10:12:39 web.1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
10:12:39 web.1  | npm ERR!     /home/learn/.npm/_logs/2020-01-10T18_12_39_116Z-debug.log
10:12:40 web.1  | exited with code 1
10:12:40 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
10:12:40 api.1  | terminated by SIGTERM
```

As requested I found two references to the babel-eslint in my package.lock.json

```
"babel-eslint": {
      "version": "10.0.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-eslint/-/babel-eslint-10.0.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-z3U7eMY6r/3f3/JB9mTsLjyxrv0Yb1zb8PCWCLpguxfCzBIZUwy23R1t/XKewP+8mEN2Ck8Dtr4q20z6ce6SoA==",
      "requires": {
        "@babel/code-frame": "7.5.5",
        "@babel/parser": "7.7.7",
        "@babel/traverse": "7.7.4",
        "@babel/types": "7.7.4",
        "eslint-visitor-keys": "1.1.0",
        "resolve": "1.12.2"
      }
```

```
and also here
```

````
"react-scripts": {
      "version": "3.3.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-scripts/-/react-scripts-3.3.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-hzPc6bxCc9GnsspWqk494c2Gpd0dRbk/C8q76BNQIENi9GMwoxFljOEcZoZcpFpJgQ45alxFR6QaLt+51qie7g==",
      "requires": {
        "@babel/core": "7.7.4",
        "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.3",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "2.15.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "2.15.0",
        "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
    etc.......
    ```
````

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the dependencies specified in your `package.json` file. If you've followed the instructions and removed any references in that file to `babel-eslint`, then I would look for references to that package in your `package-lock.json` file.

Comment: That file will specify how your dependencies are related. Try to add snippets from each section in that lock file that reference the 'babel-eslint' package. People on here may be able to help you find which dependency is causing an issue - if you can't see it clearly yourself.

Comment: @ChrisPearce i added snippets to my questions with those references.

Comment: It appears the version in my files is higher than the required version of 10.0.1, maybe using the SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true is the way to go? I just could find where to add that line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out the issue, the SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to a newly generated .env in my root directory did the trick, i figured since my babel-eslint version was higher than the required it should be fine to skip through and server started no issue. Thanks for the feedback to help me solve the issue!!